# Database Table Design : group by in the same table or create child tables and join

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am struggling that which is a better design.
There are 3 tables.
pr and pr_item and item
pr => id, name
item => id, name
pr_item => `prId`, itemId, itemPrice

pr stands for purchase request.
I'm going to make changes where the users can select multiple suppliers for the PR.
The supplier is optional though.
If there's supplier(s) selected for the PR, front end web will display the items group by suppliers. (Each supplier will have their own itemPrice)

Supplier 1
Item1 50
Item2 100

Supplier 2
Item1 30
Item3 40
Item4 80

If there's no supplier selected,
Item1 50
Item2 100
Item3 20
Item4 50

I've got 2 approaches
Approach 1 :
Add one more nullable column called supplierId into pr_item and group by supplierId while retrieving records from pr_item.

Approach 2 :
Add 2 more child tables
pr_supplier -> prId, supplierId
pr_supplier_item -> prSupplierId, itemId, itemPrice
So it will be join queries instead of group by.

Which one is a better approach?

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Can a product id have multiple supplier ? If no, approach 1 is better, neater and less join requiring

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, yes, it's possible that multiple suppliers will have the same itemId.

Comment: "yes, it's possible that multiple suppliers will have the same itemId. " Then you have a many to many relation requirement that requires a `supplier_item` table annyway.

Comment: @StevenChong then you need a supplier_item table for normalization purposes.

Comment: So approach 2 is a better approach then?

Comment: What criteria are you using to define "better"?

Comment: @brian, when it comes to database design and query performance.

Comment: @StevenChong that's not really an answer.  "Database Design" could be "number of tables", "complexity of joins", "amount of redundant data", etc.  "Query Performance" could be "high query speed", "low memory footprint", "minimal server blocking", etc.

Comment: Is this a school/homework assignment?

Comment: @Brian, No, it's not.
Oh, to put it that way, number of tables, amount of redundant data, high query speed and low memory footprint.
Thanks.

Comment: @StevenChong in my experience, speed and memory footprint are related - code that is optimized for speed typically has a bigger memory footprint, and vice versa.  Number of tables and redundancy are similarly related - typically you improve one at the expense of the other.

Comment: @Brian, I see.
In that case, I'd prefer the code to be optimized for speed as memory footprint does not concern me that much. As for number of tables vs redundancy, I'm more concerned with the redundancy.
If that's the case, in your experience, which approach would you go for?